# How to robustly test if a macro has not been set yet via pgfkeys?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfkeys, pgfopts

I am trying to define a newcommand `\ifempty` that takes three parameters:

- A macro that has been tied to a pgfkey via `/.store in` OR `/.estore in`
- What to do in case this macro has not been set yet (is empty)
- What to do in case this macro has been set (is not empty)

---

My current code is the following. Here is the code for my class:

```
% CLASS
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/11]
\LoadClass[varwidth]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    optionA/.store in = \myclass@optionA,
    optionA = ,
    optionB/.estore in = \myclass@optionB,
    optionB = ,
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myclass}

% If empty macro
\newcommand{\ifempty}[3]{%
    \ifx#1\empty% <= I'm really not sure about this line, even if it seems to work
        #2%
    \else%
        #3%
    \fi%
}

% Using the macro
\newcommand{\checkA}{\ifempty{\myclass@optionA}{A = IS EMPTY}{A = IS NOT EMPTY}}
\newcommand{\checkB}{\ifempty{\myclass@optionB}{B = IS EMPTY}{B = IS NOT EMPTY}}
\makeatother
```

---

Here is how it can be used:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\texttt{\checkA}} % A = IS EMPTY
\fbox{\texttt{\checkB}} % B = IS EMPTY
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[optionA = , optionB = ]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\texttt{\checkA}} % A = IS EMPTY
\fbox{\texttt{\checkB}} % B = IS EMPTY
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[optionA = Hello, optionB = Hey]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\texttt{\checkA}} % A = IS NOT EMPTY
\fbox{\texttt{\checkB}} % B = IS NOT EMPTY
\end{document}
```

---

**QUESTION:** It seems to work, but:

- I would like to know if `\ifempty` will fail in some cases and if so, which cases
- I would like to know if the `\ifempty` command could be made more robust

Comment: How about `\ifcat A\detokenize\expandafter{\myclass@optionA}A\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi` instead of `\ifempty{\myclass@optionA}`? This of course only works if `\myclass@optionA` is defined, is not an `\outer` token, does not process macro-arguments.

Comment: @UlrichDiez in that case, `\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\myclass@optionA}\relax` is just as robust but faster.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, but this way you need to rely on no malevolent user redefining `\relax` to s.th. like `XX` while I am paranoid when it comes to user-input. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez your code assumes that `A` isn't made active and expands to something else before it is defined. Sometimes you just have to make basic assumptions in TeX.

Comment: @Skillmon That's right, but if the code is in a macro and is loaded via `\usepackage` there is a chance of the `A` being tokenized with category 11 while `\relax` could be redefined any time...  One might use frozen-`\relax`....  ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez there is a chance of `\relax` not being redefined (as I'm afraid much of kernel code and code in basic packages will break if it is).

Comment: A value should be required with `optionA` and `optionB`. Otherwise specifying the key without trailing equal sign and without trailing value might define `\myclass@optionA`/`\myclass@optionB` to expand to the token `\pgfnovalue` so that those macros' meanings' don't equal the neaning of the macro `\empty` any more.

Comment: @Skillmon I was just kidding in some way. Nonetheless I saw code where `\relax` was redefined within a local scope which was frightening. ;-))

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes, you were, but still there is no way of being completely safe in TeX, you have at some point make assumptions for code you want to share, and assuming `\relax` has the correct meaning when your code is run should be pretty safe, there is loads of code using tests for a defined macro doing `\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\ifx\csname <something>\endcsname\relax` or something like this. Redefining `\relax` is just asking for trouble, and whoever does so should know pretty well what he's doing, and if not, will very soon end up here asking :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be maintaining option-keys that just store values and initialize to `\pgfkeysnovalue` and use a macro `\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue` for checking whether `\pgfkeysvalueof` delivers the token `\pgfkeysnovalue`.
Be aware that `\pgfkeysvalueof` delivers a `\csname..\endcsname`-thingie. Thus three expansion-steps need to be triggered on `\pgfkeysvalueof` for obtaining the tokens that form the value: The first expansion-step delivers the `\csname..\endcsname`-thingie. The second expansion-step causes `\csname` to do its work and deliver the corresponding control-sequence-token. The third expansion-step delivers the toplevel-expansion of that control-sequence-token.
Three expansion-steps require  ((1)*2+1)*2+1 = 7 `\expandafter`.

In the example below the macro `\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue` does that `\expandafter`-orgy for you so that you get the tokens
`\MYSTUFF@CheckWhetherpgfnovalue{⟨value associated to key⟩}`.
`\MYSTUFF@CheckWhetherpgfnovalue` in turn checks whether its argument contains exclamation-marks that are not nested between curly braces. If so, the argument does not consist of the single token `\pgfkeysnovalue`. That check is easy: Prepend an exclamation-mark and have TeX gobble everything until the first exclamation-mark. If that yields emptiness, then the argument itself does not hold exclamation-marks that are not nested between curly braces. Otherwise it does. The check for emptiness itself is `\ifcat A\detokenize{...}A`: The category  of the `A` is 11(letter) while `\detokenize` does not deliver any token in case its argument is empty so that in this case categorys of two category-11-`A` are compared which leads to the test taking the true-branch and does deliver only tokens of category 12(other) and/or 10(space) otherwise so that otherwise the first category-11-`A` is compared to something which is not of category 11 which leads to the test taking the false-branch.
If that test yields that `\MYSTUFF@CheckWhetherpgfnovalue` does not contain exclamation-marks that are not nested between curly braces, another test `\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovaluefork` based on delimited arguments with delimiter `!\pgfkeysnovalue!` can safely be applied for grabbing the argument behind the first occurrence of `!\pgfkeysnovalue!`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
%----This could as well go into a class file which uses pgfopts---------------------------------
\newcommand\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MYSTUFF@CheckWhetherpgfnovalue
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\MYSTUFF@CheckWhetherpgfnovalue[1]{%
  \ifcat A\detokenize\expandafter{\MYSTUFF@gobbletoexclam#1!}A%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovaluefork!#1!{\@firstoftwo}!\pgfkeysnovalue!{\@secondoftwo}!!!}%
  {\@secondoftwo}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\MYSTUFF@gobbletoexclam{\long\def\MYSTUFF@gobbletoexclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovaluefork{%
  \long\def\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovaluefork#1!\pgfkeysnovalue!#2#3!!!{#2}%
}%

\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    optionA/.initial=\pgfkeysnovalue,
    % optionA/.default=\pgfkeysnovalue,
    optionA/.value required,
    optionB/.initial=\pgfkeysnovalue,
    optionB/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{/myclass/optionB}{#1},
    % optionB/.default=\noexpand\pgfkeysnovalue,
    optionB/.value required,
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\makeatother


% Some dirty scratch-macro which carries out `\pgfkeysvalueof` to obtain the tokens that form the key's value
% and to define a scratch-macro to deliver these tokens and to spit out the meaning of that scratch-macro, with
% \meaning's-prefix removed so that you can see what tokens made the value -- this is dirty and only used in
% this example so that you can see how much expansion took place before the tokens forming the value of the
% key were stored.
% \romannumeral is abused as expansion-trigger: If the number is not positive, \romannumeral doesn't deliver
% any token. \romannumeral keeps expanding tokens while gathering the tokens that form the number to convert
% to lowercase roman notation.
% After the digit "0" you have the tokens  "\firstofone{<\expandafter-chain>}<space>%".
% \firstofone is used so that the space behind its argument's closing curly brace does not get discarded
% during tokenozation but gets tokenized as a <space-token>.
% Expansion of \firstofone makes the token \firstofone and the braces go away while keeping the tokens
% forming the <\expandafter-chain> % so that you have s.th. like
% \romannumeral0<\expandafter-chain><space-token>.
% \romannumeral found the digit 0 and is still seeking more digits, hereby expanding expandable tokens.
% Thus the <\expandafter-chain> is expanded/used for "hopping" over the <space-token> and triggering three
% expansion-steps on \pgfkeysvalueof. Then the \expandafter-chain is gone and \romannumeral finds the
% <space token> and discards it and takes it for a terminator of the digit-sequence to gather and stops
% expanding/gathering more digits. So \romannumeral gathered only the digit 0 which forms a non-positive
% number and therefore does not deliver any token in return for that.

\newcommand\pgfkeysvalueoftokens[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tempa\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0\@firstofone{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  } %<-this space must be!
  \pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}%
  \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\tempa}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\BAR{BAR}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, }|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, }

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionA}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                           {The key optionA was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionA}}

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionB}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                           {The key optionB was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionB}}

\endgroup

\bigskip

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO}|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO}

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionA}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                           {The key optionA was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionA}}

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionB}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                           {The key optionB was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionB}}

\endgroup

\bigskip

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionB=\BAR}|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionB=\BAR}

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionA}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                           {The key optionA was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionA}}

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionB}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                           {The key optionB was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionB}}

\endgroup

\bigskip

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO, optionB=\BAR}|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO, optionB=\BAR}

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionA}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                           {The key optionA was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionA}}

\MYSTUFF@pgfkeysifnovalue{/myclass/optionB}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                           {The key optionB was used: \pgfkeysvalueoftokens{/myclass/optionB}}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If you are picky:

Checking whether the option-key's value equals a default `\pgfkeysnovalue` for deducing whether the corresponding key was provided can be fooled by providing the key with the value `\pgfkeysnovalue`. In this case the key was provided but the system will assume that it was not provided. So another approach could be a key which actually is a style for carrying out two key=value-pairs: One key=value-pair for defining a macro from the value. Another key=value-pair for changing a `\@firstoftwo`/`\@secondoftwo`-flag (which was initialized to `\@firstoftwo`) to `\@secondoftwo` so that the flag can be used for forking whether the style-key was used or not:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
%----This could as well go into a class file which uses pgfopts---------------------------------
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    optionA/Value/.store in = \myclass@optionA,
    optionA/KeyUsedFlag/.initial = \@firstoftwo,
    optionA/KeyUsedFlag/.default = \@secondoftwo,
    optionA/.style={/myclass/optionA/KeyUsedFlag=\@secondoftwo, /myclass/optionA/Value=#1},
    optionA/.value required,
    % optionA/.default=default for optionA if key is specified without value,
    optionB/Value/.estore in = \myclass@optionB,
    optionB/KeyUsedFlag/.initial = \@firstoftwo,
    optionB/KeyUsedFlag/.default = \@secondoftwo,
    optionB/.style={/myclass/optionB/KeyUsedFlag=\@secondoftwo, /myclass/optionB/Value=#1},
    optionB/.value required,
    % optionB/.default=default for optionB if key is specified without value,
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\makeatother

\newcommand\BAR{BAR}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, }|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, }

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionA/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                             {The key optionA was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionA}}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionB/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                             {The key optionB was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionB}}

\endgroup
\bigskip

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO}|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionA/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                             {The key optionA was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionA}}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionB/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                             {The key optionB was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionB}}

\endgroup
\bigskip

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionB=\BAR}|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionB=\BAR}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionA/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                             {The key optionA was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionA}}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionB/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                             {The key optionB was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionB}}

\endgroup
\bigskip

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup

\verb|\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO, optionB=\BAR}|:

\pgfkeys{ /myclass/.cd, optionA=\FOO, optionB=\BAR}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionA/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionA was not used}%
                                             {The key optionA was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionA}}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionB/KeyUsedFlag}{The key optionB was not used}%
                                             {The key optionB was used: \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\myclass@optionB}}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your macro can fail if it is used in a way you didn't intend.

For instance, if you pass in more than a single token as the first argument your test tests something completely different (namely, it'll then test whether the first two tokens of your argument match). It could also fail in weird ways if you nest parts of a TeX-`\if` structure. That second case is easy to solve. The first one would require quite a lot of testing, but generally it should suffice to change the order of `#1` and `\empty`, that tests whether the first token has meaning `\empty`.

I'd code it the following way:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\newcommand\ifempty[1] % #2 and #3 are curried
  {%
    \ifx\@empty#1%
      \expandafter\@secondofthree
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
  }
\makeatother
```

This way the two arguments `<true>` and `<false>` don't end up inside of the `\if`-test and that way don't break in weird ways if they don't contain balanced TeX-ifs.

The only instability left is that if you provide more than a single token as the first argument and the first token of that argument indeed has the `\meaning` of `\@empty` (same as `\empty`) this will leave all the remainder as an argument, but that's user error.

---

Another approach could be to simply use some really unlikely value as the initial value, for instance `ltcmd`/`xparse` uses a token list that contains the same character with different category codes (and prints out as `-NoValue-`). This has to be created in a very unlikely way for any natural input, so is deemed safe-enough™. You could do something like the following for this (note that this is similar to UlrichDiez's solution testing for `\pgfnovalue` but will work even if someone used `optionA` without a value):

```
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    optionA/.store in = \myclass@optionA,
    optionA/.expand twice = \csname c_novalue_tl\endcsname,
    optionB/.estore in = \myclass@optionB,
    optionB = \csname c_novalue_tl \endcsname,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\ifunused[1]{\ifx\c_novalue_tl#1\exp_after:wN\use_ii:nnn\fi\use_ii:nn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ifunused\myclass@optionA{<true>}{<false>}
```